# Why does Workbook_BeforeClose enter value twice?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro which fires when the workbook is closed. I want it to check if a cell on a specific worksheet is blank, if so enter the string "No barcodes were scanned" then add the current date&time to the same row in another column before saving and closing the workbook.

The problem is the string gets entered twice:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets("log")

    Dim lr As Long
    lr = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    Dim IDcell As Range
    Set IDcell = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("log").Range("E" & lr)

    If IsEmpty(IDcell) Then
        Range("E" & lr).Value = "No barcodes were scanned"        
    End If

    ws.Range("C" & lr).Value = DateTime.Now
    ws.Range("C" & lr).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm"

    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: Remove the `ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True`.

Comment: may just save the workbook, not close it again, it might be kicking in the workbook_beforeclose event again

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply, I removed that line of code and it works fine now thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to auto-save the document?

Comment: Do not just remove that line. That is not the solution. See my answer.

Comment: I'm curious to know how `IDcell` would not always be empty?

Answer (score 1):

That is because of `ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True`. This will call `Workbook_BeforeClose` again. I would recommend taking this approach.

Replace `ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True` with `ThisWorkbook.Save`

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets("log")

    Dim lr As Long
    lr = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    Dim IDcell As Range
    Set IDcell = ws.Range("E" & lr)

    If IsEmpty(IDcell) Then IDcell.Value = "No barcodes were scanned"

    ws.Range("C" & lr).Value = DateTime.Now
    ws.Range("C" & lr).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm"

    ThisWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

**Note**: Change `Range("E" & lr).Value` to `IDcell.Value` else it will write to the wrong sheet if "Log" is not active.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, I  entered your suggestion and it works perfectly now many thanks!  Yes I want the date&time recorded on this worksheet whether the cell is blank or not.

Comment: Then move it out of the `IF-EndIf`. I have removed it out. You may have to refresh it to see it. I also added a small "note". You may want to see that?:) Refresh the page to see the edits